# How to detect Siri Intent shortcut launch swift app?

Tags: xcode, swiftui, siri

How can I detect if Siri launch my swift app that has not been launched.

if app is in background, after come to foreground this func will call and everything is fine

```
    func scene(_ scene: UIScene, continue userActivity: NSUserActivity) {
       if userActivity.interaction?.intent is MyCustomIntent {
          // do stuff
       }
    }
```

but if app is not launched, and Siri shortcut open my app, how can I detect it's from Siri?